# How to use $wpdb (from the template) to update the DB, without being an admin

Tags: templates, admin, wpdb

In a template file, where some backend PHP code is, how can I use the `$wpdb` to update the DB, without being logged in as admin. Every time I go to the template, I'm constantly being redirected to the login page, if I am not logged in as admin. I want to be able to use the `$wpdb` inside the plugin, to have some DB updates in the PHP code of the template - without being an admin.

Comment: `$wpdb` doesn't require you to be an admin. If you're being redirected to login then there's something somewhere else in your code doing that.

Comment: I have to include the "/wp-admin/admin.php"; to have the $wpdb. So, if I include it, it redirects to login page.

Comment: You don't have to include `admin.php` to use `$wpdb`. Are you declaring `global $wpdb` before you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use $wpdb without first declaring the global $wpdb. You should not need to enqueue admin.php in order to use $wpdb.

add:

```
global $wpdb;
```

to the top of your function instead.

If you're trying to run code in a file without passing it via wordpress (i.e. you're just navigating to /somefile.php) make sure you include wp-load.php (although this is NOT best practice).